# Laravel use morpMany with where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

Hi I am implement polymorph relation in laravel framework
currently i have 2 models
CreditLog and User

Creditlog has property sourceable , which is sourceable to User model

```
class CreditLog extends Model
{
...


    public function sourceable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

...
}
```

And then in User i have relation like this

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function creditLogs()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\CreditLog', 'sourceable');
    }

}
```

And then in some controller i need to get user credit log

```
$user = User::find($id);
$CreditLogs = $user->creditLogs;
```

Can i adding parameter in creditLogs method , i mean can laravel morphMany add the parameter like this

```
$CreditLogs = $user->creditLogs
                        ->where('created_at', '>=', $inputReq['start'])
                        ->where('created_at', '<=', $inputReq['end']);
```

Thank you for responses the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `load()` method with [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loads).

```
  $user->load(['creditLogs' => function ($query) use($inputReq) {
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', $inputReq['start'])
                ->where('created_at', '<=', $$inputReq['end']);
    }]);
```

Or use `with()` methid with [Constraing eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)